# Как называется сайт, который показывает как "дополняет" компилятор, написанный нами код

Tags: c#

например, показывает неявные методы аксессоров get/set, неявный конструктор или же приватное поле делегата для события

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://sharplab.io например

```cs
public class C
{
    public int A { get; set; }
}
```

Кажется, это то что вам нужно

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;

[assembly: CompilationRelaxations(8)]
[assembly: RuntimeCompatibility(WrapNonExceptionThrows = true)]
[assembly: Debuggable(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.Default | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.DisableOptimizations | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.EnableEditAndContinue)]
[assembly: SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.RequestMinimum, SkipVerification = true)]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.0.0.0")]
[module: UnverifiableCode]
public class C
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private int <A>k__BackingField;

    public int A
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return <A>k__BackingField;
        }
        [CompilerGenerated]
        set
        {
            <A>k__BackingField = value;
        }
    }
}
```